# React - how can I get a get response and print it in li?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the answer from the server:

```
    "status": "fail",
    "test_result": {
        "passed": [
            {
                "test": "app.test.test_auth.MyTest.test_success"
            }
        ],
        "errors": [
            {
                "test": "app.test.test_auth.MyTest.test_error",
                "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last)"
            }
        ]
    }
```

And the code of React application:

```
class Test extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            test_result: {}
        };
        this.handleCLick = this.handleCLick.bind(this)
    }

    handleCLick() {
        axios.put('http://localhost:8000/sc')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({test_result: response.data.test_result});
                })
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleCLick}>Start</button>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        {this.state.test_result}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

How can I get "test" element from every "test_result" in server's answer? I want to print it in li html elements. I read about map function and tried it, but it didn't worked. I think here should be 2 map functions for "test_result" and "errors"/"passed", should not it?

Comment: Specifically what is you trying to render is not clear. this.state.test_result is an object. You cannot put this inside a <li> like that. Please be clear what you want.

Answer (score 0):

if you try to get some data from your api you should use axios.get not put method

Comment: I have a put method in my server api

Comment: or you sure your API works fine? tested on postman? and if you trying to get data from API I suggest method PUT change to GET